# Mathematica says it converges, but doesn't say what it converges to

Tags: summation

I want to compute

```
Sum[n^2 * Binomial[ n - 1, s - 1 ] * theta^s * ( 1 - theta )^( n - s ), { n, s, Infinity }]
```

*Mathematica* says it converges when `| 1 - theta | < 1`, but doesn't say what it converges to.

In my application, `0 < theta < 1`, which definitely is in the region of convergence.

I tried using `Assuming[ ... ]` but *Mathematica* seemed to go down a rabbit hole when I did that.

Any suggestions for how to coerce *Mathematica* into divulging what it converges to would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your code as written returns an answer for me with version 10.4.1, `(s + s^2 - s theta)/theta^2`.  Try rerunning it in a new session.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Note that you can add greek letters in *Mathematica* by pressing {esc} then typing one or two letters {t}{h} and then pressing {esc} again.

Comment: thanks, bbgodfrey; i'm running 10.3.1, so perhaps i should upgrade

Comment: It successfully evaluates with version 10.3.1 on my Mac. Recommend that you try suggestion by @bbgodfrey to start with a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sum[n^2 Binomial[n - 1, s - 1] x^s (1 - x)^(n - s), {n, s, Infinity}]
```

gives in MMA

> ```
> (s+s^2-s x)/x^2
> ```